# InlineQueryResult aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть InlineQueryResult, который выводит список voice!!! объектов.

**Как сделать к ним подписи(i.e Демис Карибидис. Comedy club...), чтобы было так же, как и на фотографии?**